# Can I send a variable into laravel model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

So I'm trying to add get a specific data from a related table using the below method, but I don't know if that is the correct way to do it. here is what it looks like.

```
public function  transspecific($lid){
    return $this->belongsTo('raplet\Keepertrans')->where("lang_id", $lid);
}
```

and then I try to get data from it

```
dd($akeeper->transspecific($akeeper->id));
```

it doesn't act like there is anything but when I type `dd("hello")` inside the model, it works. so clearly I have something wrong with my relationship context

Comment: By the way, the variable `$lid` also passes correctly, it all comes down to the tiny query I make there. Any idea how can make it work?

Comment: You probably need to `get()` - `dd($akeeper->transspecific($akeeper->id)->get());`

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried that but it throws a messy SQL error that I can't work out

Comment: So give us that messy SQL error.

Comment: So it was mainly throwing an SQL error about the `pivotForigenKey`, I did some regulations and now it doesn't throw any errors, but there are no data too.

Comment: This is what I have in main relationship: `return $this->belongsToMany('raplet\Keepertrans', 'keepers', 'id', 'id');`

Comment: When I just do `return $this->belongsToMany('raplet\Keepertrans');` it gives me whiios page with the following error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'raplet_db.keeper_keepertrans' doesn't exist (SQL: select `keeper_translate`.*, `keeper_keepertrans`.`keeper_id` as `pivot_keeper_id`, `keeper_keepertrans`.`keepertrans_id` as `pivot_keepertrans_id` from `keeper_translate` inner join `keeper_keepertrans` on `keeper_translate`.`id` = `keeper_keepertrans`.`keepertrans_id` where `keeper_keepertrans`.`keeper_id` = 1 and `lang_id` = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you are trying to do is adding a [dynamic scope in laravel][1] model, which is totally fine. Except you need to declare the scope seperated from relationship method.

Relationship:

```
public function keepertrans(){
    return $this->belongsTo('raplet\Keepertrans');
}
```

Scoped:

```
public function transspecific($lid){
    return $this->keepertrans()->where("lang_id", $lid);
}
```

Then you can call the scope with a `get()` to execute the query builder:

```
(SomeOtherRelatedModel::first())->transspecific($someId)->get();
```

Comment: I don't understand why I need `get()` here

Comment: It seems like I made some syntax errors in the code so this is actually working.

Answer (score 1):

The methods available in Eloquent model for relationship are different than what you need. Whenever you need to add a custom function which internally adds some filters to your query (builder), you need to use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes)

The generic rule of scope function is `scope` + `yourfunction`

In your case you will need to create `scopeTranspecific` function.

Each scope gets the first argument as builder which you update inside the function. The later arguments are optional.

```
public function scopeTranspecific($query, $lid){

    return $query->keepertrans()->where("lang_id", $lid);
}
```

And then you can use it :

```
Model::where('column1' , 'value')->transpecific($id)->get()
```

If you just dump it without `->get()` you will get the query builder instance. You will have to do `->get()` to get the data

Comment: Excuse me, sir, is the `$query` represent the main model or is it an entire query itself?

Comment: It is the instance of query builder. Conceptually what Model::query() gives you. obviously it gets updated as you apply where clauses and join etc. :)